# Which diff formats are supported by Git?

Tags: git, git-diff, gitattributes

In `.gitattributes` I see things like:

```
*.htm           text diff=html
*.html          text diff=html
*.java          text diff=java
...                  diff=astextplain
```

How are those called, diff formats, diff outputs ?

**Where** is the list of all supported diff formats ?

Comment: Well, a google for "gitattributes diff" provides a very relevant manual page which has a list of built-in ones: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: @Gimby ^^ ashamed, was probably using find on 'diff=java' or something like that... I stumbled on this link which looked like the big doc: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes, but had no such list

Comment: Is it reasonable to suppose that `html/xhtml` would work on `xml` too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git just refers to these as "attributes" in general, and describes them in [the `gitattributes` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header).  The `diff=` setting is the "diff attribute", and for whatever reason, the list of built-in attributes is in the section titled **Defining a custom hunk-header**:

> First, in .gitattributes, you would assign the diff attribute for
>    paths.
>
> ```
> *.tex   diff=tex
> ```

(this is where Git labels this the "diff attribute").

> There are a few built-in patterns to make this easier, and `tex` is one of them, so you do not have to write the above in your configuration file (you still need to enable this with the attribute mechanism, via `.gitattributes`). The following built in patterns are available: ...

(I won't reproduce the whole list here, which is fairly long.  Note that different versions of Git have different built-in patterns, so you should look at the documentation for your specific version of Git, which you should be able to view with `git help gitattributes`.)

Comment: Also here (see comment of Gimby): https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header

Comment: Anyone know where to find the specific configurations for these presets?

Comment: @DylanYoung: last time I checked, I found them built into the C source. Ah, here they are, in [userdiff.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/userdiff.c). (Er, that is, assuming you mean specifically the `diff=` ones. If you mean attributes in general, Git has ones *it* uses but you can *define* your own and use them for your own purposes, so there is no master list of all attributes.)